# Understanding the smoothness of the Poincaré homology sphere

Tags: geometric-topology, symmetry

*Cross posted from [physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/713524/understanding-the-smoothness-of-poincar%c3%a9-dodecahedral-space/713538#713538) on suggestion of a commenter. However, please explain any topology terminology in the answers for a non-expert!*

I've been trying to wrap my head around Poincaré Dodecahedral Space, aka the Poincaré homology sphere, which was suggested as a cosmological model after the release of WMAP cosmic microwave background data but contradicted by the improved Planck mission data. This is commonly described as gluing opposite faces of a dodecahedron, e.g. this figure from *The Shape of Space* by Jeffrey R. Weeks (reproduced [here](https://www.rudyrucker.com/blog/2008/04/20/is-the-universe-infinite/)):

[image: Dodecahedron with "Glue" on top and bottom faces]

Since this is a 3-manifold, it must locally look like euclidean space. However, I don't understand how this is possible near the corners. It seems like mapping points near a corner to the opposite sides of the dodecahedron will result in points far apart. For instance, given the labels from this figure (Threlfall & Seifert, 1931, pg 66, uploaded [here](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Poincar%C3%A9%27s_homology_sphere#Threlfall.26Seifert1931)):

[image]

if we consider the center corner *I*, it is surrounded by $C_1^+$, $C_3^+$ and $C_4^+$. However, applying the glue operation we get the other three *I* corners, each of which is bounded by a different set of faces.

Does this imply that it's not just the opposing faces which are glued, but that there are actually 4 equivalent positions for any point in the dodecahedron? That seems wrong to me, since then the actual space would be something like three pentagonal pyramids merged and you'd get a singularity at the center. What am I overlooking here?

Comment: For 3d manifolds you can always "smooth out the corners", converting a piecewise-linear manifolds to smooth manifolds. In the case of Poincare sphere, the best way to do this is to work not with Euclidean but with spherical polyhedra. Then the angles at the corners will add up to $2\pi$ and you will even get a Riemannian metric of constant curvature on the manifold.

Comment: Thanks, thinking about the spherical polyhedra helps a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't quite understand what any of these sentences means:

> ...each of which is bounded by a different set of faces.

> Does this imply that it's not just the opposing faces which are glued, but that there are actually 4 equivalent positions for any point in the dodecahedron? That seems wrong to me, since then the actual space would be something like three pentagonal pyramids merged and you'd get a singularity at the center. What am I overlooking here?

But hopefully this answers your question anyway: yes, there are $4$ equivalent positions for every corner. This gluing is a topological (or smooth) gluing, not a geometric one; it doesn't know anything about angles and so forth. The dodecahedron here is not "rigid," it is allowed to bend and stretch as necessary.

This is related to the fact that unlike, say, the cube, whose opposite faces can be identified (rigidly!) to get a $3$-torus, in such a way that angles add up and so forth, dodecahedra can't tile Euclidean space. Dodecahedra *can* tile [hyperbolic space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_space), and the [Seifert-Weber space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert%E2%80%93Weber_space) is a $3$-manifold which can be constructed using such a tiling, the [order-$5$ dodecahedral honeycomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-5_dodecahedral_honeycomb). But as it turns out, no such tiling produces the Poincare homology sphere, because its universal cover is the $3$-sphere $S^3$ and so can't be either Euclidean or hyperbolic $3$-space.

The Poincare homology sphere can be given a [geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrization_conjecture#The_eight_Thurston_geometries) but it has positive [curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature_of_Riemannian_manifolds) (spherical) rather than zero (Euclidean) or negative (hyperbolic); to do this you can construct it as the quotient of $S^3$ by an isometric action of the [binary icosahedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_icosahedral_group), which can e.g. be constructed using [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion).

Comment: I don't understand much of this answer but I think it covers the main points: the 4 points on the boundary are in fact equivalent; the points within the boundary are unique and smooth; and the resulting space is neither Euclidean nor hyperbolic. The equivalence doesn't lead to discontinuities, but just means there are points which are far apart in one visualization but actually close together when considering the boundary.